# Get data from database before run app

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have application which have spinner and in this spinner I have data from my database.

I use `async task` to get data from database, and in `onPostExecute` method I add to spinner this data.

My main problem is that when i run app, in my spinner data isn't available, since async task hasn't finish yet.

My question is what I have to do that my data from database are in spinner before I run my app ??

Comment: Please post the code.

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout covering the spinner displaying a loading message and set this layouts visibility to GONE in the post execute method of your asynctask

Or load your data in your main activity and start your spinner activity when the task is complete

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the loading simple data like spinner data is very fast (it's usually 100,200 milliseconds). Then you dont have to load data before opening the app. Maybe your problem is doing too many things with `AsyncTask`. `AsyncTask`s are run in a queue, one after another one finished. So, my suggestion is using `Thread` for loading spinner data as:

```
new LoadingSpinnerDataThread().start(); // it's better if you can use RxAndroid.
```